# iPhone and Mac fonts problem

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I try to use Helvetica font with size 13 pt. I have a problem, because I created an image with some text with this font and font size. Added it to my iPhone project, then I created a UILabel, added top on this image which was created in photoshop, I've used the same font and font size and it's totally different. Why is that?

Comment: Can you post screenshots ? Also, I think the font size on iOS is not in points but pixels, but I might be mistaken.

Comment: Ok, I try the point and pixel thing, thanks for the tip, if it will not work then I post a screenshot.

Comment: DarkDust, if it works, post the answer as an answer.

Comment: It doesn't work at the moment. The documentation says that the UIFont is in points, which means it is in pixels. That's bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS, the font size is in pixels instead of points which might explain the difference.

Comment: Yes, you have right, I've checked the documentation. How can I get rid of it?

Comment: You can't change the unit in iOS. Guess you have to find the correct size either through trial and error or you can try to measure it: draw a text like "Tj" in Photoshop and measure the pixel distance between to topmost and bottommost pixels.

Comment: I tried it, but it isn't enough good. It has 1-2 pixel difference, and this makes the graphics bad. :( Any other solution?

Comment: You are aware that the size is a float, so you can pass e.g. 6.5 ?

Comment: I don't know if it is a float, but it's a good idea, I try it, I never thought that it can be float.

Comment: I've tried it, it's not perfect, but it seems to work. In photoshop I've set a font size of 12 and in interface builder I've set a 30.5 font size. The first letter is ok, the other ones has 1 pixel difference, but it is so little that the user can't see. Maybe a perfect one who can see every pixel difference. :) If anybody has a better solution please don't hesitate to write here. I also tried the 30.65, but it seems it isn't working.

Answer (score 3):

1 *inch* = 72 *pt* = 96 *px*, which means **9pt = 12px**