# How to get the correct font sizes from Photoshop into iOS

Tags: ios, fonts, photoshop

I have a design in an psd file. So I copied all text properties (fontname, size (in pt), color, etc) into code and run it. I did a screenshot and compared that to the design.
I am wondering, why is iOS (in my case) rendering the font sizes (in pt) smaller than Photoshop does?

Does pt depend on the screen resolution? Is there maybe a helper function that I could calculate it from a px size?

Comment: This question is almost the same as [iPhone and Mac fonts problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904164/iphone-and-mac-fonts-problem).

Comment: Very good answer here, seems to be exact: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6107836/1804403

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the easiest way (not sure if the most accurate one) would be to take pixel values (not point ones) from Photoshop and use those instead. Assuming you are designing Photoshop files that are 320x480 (not retina) this should work nicely and quite accurately.

Here's a sample, left is in Photoshop at size 12px and right is in iOS Simulator at 12pt.
[image: Sample 12px vs 12pt]

Comment: Sorry to resurrect an old question; but in case someone Googles this, I've had success matching font sizes if you set Photoshop to use a DPI of 326 pixels/inch and set the Type Units to Pixels under the Units & Rulers setting.

Comment: @nness If you put this in an answer (instead of a comment), I would upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change document resolution to 144 pixels/Inch and keep screen width 640px (for portrait orientation).
Goto Image > Image Size > Resolution

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop ratina images-12Pt = Ios-6Pt(X=2*Y)
photoshop not ratina images-12pt = Ios-12pt(X=Y)